# Passing arguments to IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE

Tags: c++, mfc

MFC `IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE` is creates object in below way

```
CObject* PASCAL class_name::CreateObject() \
        { return new class_name; }
```

Which calls default constructor. I wanted to call parameterised constructor with a customized parameter.

Is there any way to pass an argument to `IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE` macro?
How `IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE` is being called, can anyone please explain?

Comment: This macro is created my Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/5fsfk9dy(v=vs.140)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to pass an argument to `IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE` macro?

No. This macro expands to functionality required by MFC to implement dynamic object creation. This is used for example when dynamically constructing views, or deserializing an object from disk. The macro itself is never called. Details are outlined in [Run-Time Object Model Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/run-time-object-model-services).

This restriction does not imply, that you weren't allowed to provide user-defined constructors. You can still do that, and invoke those constructors in your code, although I doubt that makes for very maintainable code. The framework will not ever invoke anything but the default constructor.

---

Note, that the default constructor is defined to be the constructor, that can be invoked without passing any arguments. A constructor with one or more arguments, where all of them have default arguments assigned, is still considered the default constructor.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Can you please let me know how the parameterized constructor can be called using IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE?

Comment: It can't be called, unless that parameterized constructor is the default constructor. It's not immediately clear, what problem you are ultimately trying to solve here. Regardless of what it is, the way `IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE` is implemented is baked into MFC's code, and cannot be changed from user code.

Comment: I have defined something like this 
IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE(Control, COleControl)
I need to pass a parameter(some application name) to the class Control, during the construction phase. I am facing problem to do so.

Comment: You can't, it's that simple. There's no way for you to provide that argument to the framework for use in all the places where it calls `CreateObject`, a function that takes no arguments. Either provide default arguments to your implementation, in case the application name is known at compile time, or look for a different solution to the problem.

Comment: That different solution can be found here: [Class Factories and Licensing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/class-factories-and-licensing). Unfortunately, you didn't ask about *that* question. This answer addresses the question you did ask.

Comment: I am not fluent in MFC, Could you please help me to understand how to use class factories to provide an extra argument in the constructor.

Comment: You can't. The available set of constructor signatures of dynamically createable objects in MFC is fixed. You are trying to solve a problem using the wrong tools. OLE/ActiveX controls require different implementations, and different preprocessor macros. This is explained in the link I posted in my previous comment. If you find yourself confused, putting all those details together, seriously consider getting your hands on good reference material. [Programming Windows with MFC](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1572316950) by Jeff Prosise is still the most valuable resource for any MFC developer.